# Opening a file with the default viewer on Linux

Tags: c, linux

I am working at an OS independent file manager (mostly Windows and Linux), and I am wondering if there is a Linux way to open a file in its default viewer. For example, open a html file with Firefox, an .avi with vlc, and so on.
On Windows, there is a function ShellExecute() that does that, but my understanding is that on Linux it is not that simple, and each desktop environment has a specific way.
I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`xdg-open(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open). It works on all [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) compliant desktops.

Answer (score 2):

The default programs for different mime-types are defined in /etc/mailcap and $HOME/.mailcap, indexed by file type and action (display, edit, print). The command line interface is run-mailcap. See also the manpages run-mailcap(1) and mailcap(5).

Answer (score 1):

It depends what desktop environment you're using in Linux. Gnome for example has a [MIME database](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile-gnome/docs/gnome-vfs/html/MIME-Database.html) you can use to find out what to launch for a given file.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of suspected that :/ Any way to determine which desktop environment it is running under?

Answer (score 0):

Sahil Muthoo has given you good advice. I will just give further examples.

If xdg-open is not available you can also use "*gnome-open*" for GNOME and "*kfmclient*" for KDE.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that xdg-open works quite well, even on lxde :)